# Query Posts to fetch Posts with Unique Tag

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I am trying to write a query post such that it returns a list fixed list of posts from a category along with any of the one tag associated with it.  For eg:

```
<?php $arg = array('cat' => '1','showposts' => 10,'offset' => 0); query_posts($arg); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a class="post-link" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); $count=0; if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id); $count++; if ($count == 1) 
{ echo '<a class="tag-link" href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">#'.$tag->name.'</a>'; } } } ?>
```

#### Posts in Topic A

Post_Title_1 #tag1
Post_Title_2 #tag2
Post_Title_3 #tag3
Post_Title_4 #tag2 <-- I don't wan't this Post one as Tag2 has been displayed already.

The issue is I want only posts with unique tags to be shown....  How can i do that... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$arg = array('cat' => '1','showposts' => 10,'offset' => 0);
query_posts($arg);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<a class="post-link" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
if (!$used_tags) $used_tags = array();
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
        if ( !in_array($tag->term_id, $used_tags) ) {
            array_push($used_tags, $tag->term_id);
            echo '<a class="tag-link" href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">#'.$tag->name.'</a>';
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Not tested though!

Comment: Changed `break 2;` to `break;` and its working fine. Thanks.

I also needed to filter out posts in `hidden` tag so just added  `&& $tag->slug != 'hidden'` after `!in_array($tag->term_id, $used_tags)` and its working fine too (if anyone is using this code).